# Undefined variable PHP POO

Tags: php

estoy recien empezando en el mundo PHP, y me surgio un problema al cual non le encuentro solucion, busque por todos lados y no llegue a encontrar algo que me pudiera ayudar.
Mi situacion es la siguente, estoy trabajando a un cuestionario y al momento de instanciar el objeto me salta el error `Undefined variable`.
este es el objeto:

```
<?php
    class quiz {
      public $name;
      public $author;
      public $subject;
      public $questions = [];

      public function __construct($n,$a,$s){
        $this->name = $n;
        $this->author = $a;
        $this->subject =$s;
      }
      public function addq($q){
        $this->questions[] = new question($q);
      }
      public function getName(){
        echo  $this->name;
      }
    }
    class question {
     public $question;
     public $answers = [];

     public function __construct($q) {
       $this->question = $q;
     }

     public function adda($a, $v){
       $this->answers[] = new answer($a, $v);
     }

     public function getQuestion(){
       echo  $this->question;
     }
   }
   class answer {
     public $answer = [];

     public function __construct($a, $v) {
        $this->answer[] = array(
         'risposta' => $a,
         'valore' => $v,
        );
     }

      public function getAnswer(){
        //codificazione in json per una lettura più efficace
        $tmp = json_encode(array_column($this->answer, 'risposta'), TRUE);
        //sotto stringa per prendere unicamente il valore della risposta senza [""] inserito da json
        $tmp = substr($tmp,2,strlen($tmp)-4);
        //stampa della variabile preparata in precedenza
         print_r($tmp);
      }
   }
?>
```

y instancio el objeto `quiz` aca:

```
   <?php
      session_start();

     //reindirizzamento
     $urlRedirect = 'http://localhost:8888/prova%20ogetti/view/aggiungidomanda.php';
     header('Location:'.$urlRedirect);

     //autoload di classi esistenti all'interno del progetto
     function __autoload($classname) {
        $filename = "../model/". $classname .".php";
        include_once($filename);
     }

     //presa de  dati inviati tramite post
     $name = $_POST['nome'];
     $author = $_POST['autore'];
     $subject = $_POST['materia'];
     //$image = $_POST['file'];

     //creazione del ogetto quiz
     $obj = new quiz($name, $author, $subject);

     //inizializzazione delle variabili di sessione
     $_SESSION['obj'] = serialize($obj);
     $_SESSION['state'] = "q";
     session_write_close();
  ?>
```

el problema me surge cuando trato de agregarle la pregunta con las respectivas respuestas en otro file :

```
   <?php
     session_start();
    //iniziamo la sessione
    //reindirizzamento automatico
     $urlRedirect = 'http://localhost:8888/prova%20ogetti/view/aggiungidomanda.php';
    //header('Location:'.$urlRedirect);

    include("../model/quiz.php");


    //prendiamo l'ogetto "quiz" creato in precedenza dalla variabile di sessione
    $obj = unserialize($_SESSION['obj']);

    // prendiamo le variabile passate tramite post dalla vista aggiungidomanda
    $domanda = $_POST['domanda'];
    $risp1 = $_POST['risp1'];
    if($_POST['val1'] = null){$val1 = "false";}else{$val1 = "true";};
    $risp2 = $_POST['risp2'];
    if($_POST['val2'] = null){ $val2 = "false";}else{$val2 = "true";};
    $risp3 = $_POST['risp3'];
    if($_POST['val3'] = null){ $val3 = "false";}else{$val3 = "true";};
    $risp4 = $_POST['risp4'];
    if($_POST['val4'] = null){ $val4 = "false";}else{$val4 = "true";};

    $obj->addq($domanda);

    //aggiungo la risposta e il valore corrispondente nella domanda rispettiva
    $obj->$questions[count($obj->$questions)-1]->adda($risp1,$val1);
    $obj->$questions[count($obj->$questions)-1]->adda($risp2,$val2);
    $obj->$questions[count($obj->$questions)-1]->adda($risp3,$val3);
    $obj->$questions[count($obj->$questions)-1]->adda($risp4,$val4);

    session_write_close();
  ?>
```

el error que me sale seria este : `Undefined variable: questions in ... on line 34`
en que me estoy equivocando ?

Comment: Tú no has creado ninguna instancia de la clase `quiz`, que es la que tiene una propiedad llamada `questions`.  Por lo que dice el comentario en italiano, la instancia del objeto se crea aquí:  `$obj = unserialize($_SESSION['obj']);`. Puedes probar el estado de `$obj` haciendo `var_dump($obj);`. Si no, deberías entonces crear una nueva instancia de la clase `quiz` para poder usarla.

Comment: Igual tambien que compruebe lo que tiene en questions

Comment: `object(quiz)#1 (4) { ["name"]=> string(4) "ciao" ["author"]=> string(4) "ciao" ["subject"]=> string(4) "ciao" ["questions"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(question)#2 (2) { ["question"]=> string(3) "and" ["answers"]=> array(0) { } } } }` esto es lo que tengo antes del error, osea me agrega la pregunta pero no me deja agregarle las respuestas por el `undefined variable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La manera correcta de acceder a una instance property `questions` sería

```
$obj->questions
```

Y no

```
$obj->$questions
```

De todas maneras, ese serializar las clases para meterlas en una variable de sesión es un poco jugar con una caja negra. Puede funcionarte para este ejemplo en particular, pero hay objetos que no son serializables y si una clase constituye o utiliza uno de esos objetos (por ejemplo la conexión a una BBDD) hay cosas que se van a romper.

En segundo lugar (y esto no tiene relación con el error de tu pregunta), estás declarando un autoloader:

```
 function __autoload($classname) {
    $filename = "../model/". $classname .".php";
    include_once($filename);
 }
```

El cual te permite instanciar `quiz` sin hacer el include manual.

```
 $obj = new quiz($name, $author, $subject);
```

Pero no te permitiría instanciar un objeto `question` ni `answer` sin inclusión manual de `quiz.php` como estás haciendo en el tercer script.

Si en este momento te resulta es porque como están todas en el mismo archivo, la inclusión manual en el tercer script se trae anecdóticamente la declaración de las otras dos clases.

Sería más sano tener `quiz.php`, `question.php` y `answer.php` cada uno conteniendo la declaración de una clase, y en todos tus otros scripts hacer un include_once del script que declara el autoloader. Esto es sólo una sugerencia de diseño, pero te hará la vida más fácil en el futuro.

Comment: no te puedo creer que me rompi la cabeza por un error tan banal ! muchisimas gracias! sobretodo por los consejos que ya voy a meter en practica